# Unset object variable's property in a method, affected its value in parent scope?

Tags: php, simplexml, unset

I made a small library to read database-exported xml file, and output it as an structured associate array. It can also filter the output by table columns.

After I've done the code, when I play with this class I find something weird. `unset` is acting as if the variable was passed by reference.

I could not spot any possible bugs, so I put up my the particular method where `$this->rows` is being set, hoping someone could enlight me.

```
private function populateData($rowLimit)
    {
        if (!$this->getColumns()) {
            throw new ReaderException(__FUNCTION__ . " # Unable to get columns name.");
        }

        // database->tableName->rows
        $rows = $this->getSimpleXmlElement()->children()->children();

        if ($this->getFilteredColumns()) {
            $toRemoves = array_values(array_diff($this->getColumns(),
                $this->getFilteredColumns()));
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                foreach ($toRemoves as $toRemove) {
                    unset($row->{$toRemove});
                }
            }
        }

        $rows = $this->simpleXmlToArray($rows)['row'];

        if ($rowLimit) {
            $limited = [];
            for ($i = 0; $i < $rowLimit; $i++) {
                $limited[] = $rows[$i];
            }
            $this->setRows($limited);
        } else {
            $this->setRows($rows);
        }

        $structArray = [
            'database' => $this->getDatabaseName(),
            'table' => $this->getTableName(),
            'columns' => !$this->getFilteredColumns() ? $this->getColumns()
                : $this->getFilteredColumns(),
            'rows' => $this->getRows()
        ];

        $this->setStruct($structArray);

        return $this;
    }


$xml = new SomeXmlReader($companyTableFilePath);
$xml->get(1);
```

output:

```
[
 "database" => "myDatabase",
 "table" => "companies",
 "columns" => [
   "id",
   "name",
   "license_no",
   "phone",
   "created",
   "modified",
 ],
 "rows" => [
   [
     "id" => "1",
     "name" => "SOME COMPANY NAME",
     "license_no" => "884652",
     "phone" => null,
     "created" => "2015-09-25 16:01:57",
     "modified" => "2015-09-25 16:01:57",
   ],
 ],
]
```

When I tried to filter off some columns, I do

```
$xml->setFilteredColumns(['id','name'])->get(1);
```

it returns the result as expected: the columns have been trimmed.
Output:

```
[
 "database" => "myDatabase",
 "table" => "companies",
 "columns" => [
   "id",
   "name",
 ],
 "rows" => [
   [
     "id" => "1",
     "name" => "SOME COMPANY NAME",
   ],
 ],
]
```

However, right after this line, when I test it again with

```
$xml->setFilteredColumns(['id','name','phone'])->get(1);
```

on the next line, something went wrong. The output is:

```
[
 "database" => "myDatabase",
 "table" => "companies",
 "columns" => [
   "id",
   "name",
   "phone",
 ],
 "rows" => [
   [
     "id" => "1",
     "name" => "SOME COMPANY NAME",
   ],
 ],
]
```

After some tracing, I find that `$this->getSimpleXmlElement()` had been modified by `unset`. Within this app lifecycle, I can no longer get the complete/original value of `$this->getSimpleXmlElement()`.

Is there a fundamental mistake I've made, or this is a PHP language behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

There is rather a lot of code to follow through here - consider making [a more compact example](https://stackoverflow.com/mcve) - but it sounds like your misunderstanding is fairly simple.

Objects are never copied when going from one scope to another, because a variable doesn't "contain" an object, it "points at" one (this is not quite the same as pass-by-reference, but the effect is similar in many cases).

So when you run `unset($row->{$toRemove});`, you are indeed editing the `$row` object, and by extension the whole SimpleXML document.

If you want a copy of an object to work with, you have to explicitly "clone" it, as [discussed in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php).